# Should the red light on my NES flash when no cartridge is inserted?

Tags: nes

Should the red light flash with no games inserted? I haven't got any games to test properly. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 10):

Yes, the red light should flash when no game is inserted. It also can do that when a game is in there, that just means it is not reading it properly.

Is the NES faulty? No. This is normal.

Comment: in the case of the NES, faulty *was* normal. :)

Comment: I believe the light flashes because the console is resetting, because the lockout chip isn't there. (iirc, without it, it just sits idle on a dead screen.) Just in case you were interested in the technical details, I guess.

Comment: @Xkeeper, you are correct. It's a mixture of that and there is no cartridge to read. It's basically 'if can't read - wait .5 - 1 second(s), reset, try again'

Comment: As soon as I saw this question I had to cast deep back into my memory, yes that is normal along with a flashing lavender screen.